# WordPress Custom Rewrite Rule towards Custom Page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Hi I have a wordpress based website that contains movies and tv-shows. Meta datas include the year of release, e.g. Inception has 2010 as year_of_release, the key of the meta data value. I need to do something to make a custom link so that it would be like

`website.com/year/2010`

and it would show a custom page like `year.php` or whatever and take `2010` as a GET parameter so that I can show every movie released in 2010, or 2011 or whatever the parameter is.

Basically it would be like `website.com/category/sub-category` but I don't want it to be a category, since the year is saved as meta data and it would be wasteful to create a subcategory for every year.

Can anyone tell me a way to make a custom rewrite rule or to make a redirect rule to force a link like that to show a custom page of mine? Thanks in advance to everyone, I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add rewrite rule in functions.php

```
function year_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^year/([0-9]+)/?', 'page-year.php?year=$matches[1]',    'top');
}
add_action('init', 'year_rewrite');
```

in your page-year.php create the loop to query the post by post meta year from the url parameter year.

Then go to Settings->Permalinks and just Save so WordPress will flush the new rules and it will work.

Comment: 1. The syntax docs is here https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule 2. You should have a child theme for your site with functions.php in it. If you don't have one yet , create one to your themehttps://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. A tip for whoever will read this: after adding any code of this type (rewrite rule), go to Settings->Permalinks and just Save so wordpress will flush the new rules and it will work. Otherwise the new rules won't be applied.

Comment: Great. Added save the permalink part to the answer.