# Wordpress - Custom URL routes

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a newbie in Wordpress, so excuse me if I ask a noob question.

I want to redirect some of the URLs to a specific page (deal.php). Now, these set of URLs (regex provided for these URLS) does not exist on my server. So, currently my WP returns 404 error. However, I still want to load `deal.php` and let it decide.

My `deal.php` fires a GET request to an API, and my processing will follow thereafter.

For eg:- If I have an url (for eg) `/properties/1/`  and it's permalink is not available in my WP settings, I want it load `deal.php` page, and let my API decide the further processing.

Here's what I've tried reading on multiple other [questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes):-

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );
function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'properties/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'deal.php?pagename=single-deal&property_id=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26388_query_vars' );
function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'property_id';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Comment: this should work but make sure you add also the `pagename` query var to your custom `$query_vars`. Also make sure that `deal.php` page can be found by wordpress. Where is it located inside a plugin? A custom theme page? You should set the appropruiate url path for `deal.php` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule). This is the problem i see

Comment: sorry no need to add `pagename` query var.

Comment: thanks @NikosM. for a quick response. Could you please give a demo example.

Comment: No. `deal.php` is not inside a plugin. It's with other php pages.

Comment: it depends where the `deal.php` page resides (is it on a theme folder or in root folder) so wordpress can find it when the request is made and url matches the condition

Comment: I've installed a theme, and it's inside the installed theme folder.

Comment: try using `index.php` instead of `deal.php` like `add_rewrite_rule(
        'properties/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=single-deal&property_id=$matches[1]',
        'top' );` as pagename already points to single-deal page in theme

Comment: 404. Not found.

Comment: What is `page-name`?

Comment: is there a `single-deal.php` page in your theme folder?

Comment: pagename is the parameter used in wordpress url rewritting to identify which page to load from theme folder

Comment: Yes. Basically, I mis-typed `deal.php` as `single-deal.php`/

Comment: Both deal and single-deal are the same. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185317/discussion-between-pythonenthusiast-and-nikos-m).

Comment: @NikosM. - Any thoughts please!

Comment: Okay. I just understood what `add_rewrite_rule` does. It routes the matched url to the page with query parameters (if required). HOWEVER, my requirement is NOT to route. I want to load the `single-deal.php` when a regex matched URL is browsed. This URL does not exist on my server. Please provide help!

Comment: @Nikos M - Any thoughts on this please?

Comment: younhave to make sure the page you are trying to load through the url_rewrite_rule exists and can be found by wordpress. This is what I think maybe adding a listing of the theme folder in your question could help. Also check examples of `add_rewrite_rule` online to see how it handles pages which are theme pages

Comment: for example take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059475/wordpress-custom-rewrite-rule-towards-custom-page and https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/custom-page-template-page-based-on-url-rewrite--wp-30564

Comment: also this https://metabox.io/how-to-create-a-virtual-page-in-wordpress/